# Windows 10 "Device Limit Reached"

Tags: windows-activation, product-key, windows-10-upgrade, windows-10

I have Windows 10 installed on 3 laptops and only 1 of them can be activated. I checked the product keys and they are the SAME. All 3 of those laptops had their own product keys prior to the upgrade. They are also connected to the same Microsoft account.
Edit: I just received an email with the following message:

> Hi Daniel,
>
> It looks like you've reached your device limit for installing apps and
> games from the Store on your Windows 10 device. If you want to install
> apps and games from the Store on another Windows 10 device, remove a
> device from the device list.
>
> [Remove a device now](http://account.microsoft.com/devices/store)

What is the deal here?

Update 7/30/15: I was able to successfully activate on a second laptop. Maybe they fixed it?

Update 8/1/15: Problem seems to be solved. Activated successfully on desktop, 3 laptops, and surface pro 3.

Comment: What method did you use to install Windows 10 on them? Did you reserve prior?

Comment: @MC10 Yes I reserved on all 3 of them.

Comment: @Daniel Answer both questions please.

Comment: @MC10 1) I opened the GWX app and hit the "continue" button. Then accepted the license agreement. Then it automatically rebooted to the black screen installation process. 2) Yes, I reserved using the same Microsoft account on all three laptops.

Comment: Apparently the new limit is 10 installs (down from 81 for 8.1). Maybe you have some old dead devices still connected via the account? Phones or tablets? - http://www.windowscentral.com/windows-10-store-apps-will-be-limited-10-device-installs-same-microsoft-account

Comment: @goblinbox I definitely don't have 10 installs. I only tested on three laptops and 1 virtual machine.

Comment: So I assume you clicked on the link and determined Microsoft also detect you only having 4 machines linked?  How did you determine they have the same product key exactly?

Comment: @Ramhound Yup, oddly it only showed two of the laptops and the virtual machine.

Comment: @Daniel - So I have read an article that indicates if you run `wsreset` it might make a difference.

Comment: @Daniel - If you solved the problem you should self-answer.

Answer (score 1):

I received the same email last night. For me, the problem seems to have been triggered by a Windows 8.1 device that I upgraded that did not properly activate after the upgrade. I assume that I received the email because my Microsoft account was associated with the non-activated install.

Activating Windows seems to have resolved the issue.

Comment: I'm not on Windows, but curious: when upgrading an activated Windows installation, is activation of Windows 10 then still needed?

Comment: @Arjan - Yes.  Of course it is.

Comment: @Ramhound, my bad if I was not clear, just to be sure: I meant *manual* activation.